# calculus problem from International Mathematics Competition for University Students 2005

Tags: calculus, integration, contest-math

[image]

How to write it formally: I tried integration by parts and was able to prove it, but I do not know how to write it correctly, meaning I don't know where to put which limit when using IBP in definite integrals and not at all familiar with double integrals.
Here is the link from where the problem is taken:
https://www.imc-math.org.uk/imc2005/day1_solutions.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)=1$ for all $x$ then LHS is $\frac  1 2$ and RHS is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

I think the identity is not correct, there must be a coefficient $1/2$ for the right-hand side. To proving it you need just change the order of integration among $t$ and $x$. Then you get the double of the integral, add it up you get the identity.

$I=\int_0^1f(x)\int_0^xf(t)dtdx=\int_0^1f(t)\int_t^1f(x)dxdt=\int_0^1f(x)\int_x^1f(t)dtdx$

so $2I=\int_0^1f(x)(\int_0^xf(t)dt+\int_x^1f(t)dt)dx=(\int_0^1f(x)dx)^2$.

Comment: yes yes sry, you are right there is a cofficient of 1/2

Comment: nope cant understand what you did there could you break it down for me, i am not familiar with changing the order of intergration.

Comment: @ffrff I think you should read a bit about double integral and changing of order integration. Here for example https://mathinsight.org/double_integral_change_order_integration_examples  then you will able to understand it easily.